# Selecting and Highlighting Entities in AutoCad VBA

Tags: excel, vba, select, highlight, autocad

I am working in AutoCad and with Excel VBA. In my code, I read in a Excel Worksheet the info that I need from the drawing including the Handle of the Entities I am interested on.

My next step is to verify some Acad Drawing info based on Excel calculations. For this, I pick the Entities Handle ID on Excel and it highlights the Entity on Acad. Some times Entities highlighting doesn't do enough contrast to differentiate the entity of my interest between all the other objects.

It would be better if the entity I need to verify get selected, as it is made in Acad environment with the mouse. Unfortunately, the practical way to verify the info is accessing by the Handle ID.

I have looked for alternatives in Internet and found something regarding with SelectionSets, but result was not different of just highlight the entity.

Any suggestion to select (as with the mouse) or to improve the colors or highlighting characteristics of the entities?

The code I am using is:

'''Sub dfSelHnd()

```
Dim actldwg As AcadDocument
Dim tAr(0) As AcadEntity 'Add items to selectionset must be done with arrays

Dim rng As Range
Dim txt As String

''---
''---
''---

Set rng = Selection
Set actldwg = AutoCAD.Application.ActiveDocument

txt = rng.Value '' txt is the HandleID

Set tAr(0) = actldwg.HandleToObject(txt)

Call zoomit(actldwg, tAr(0))
tAr(0).Highlight (True)
```

End Sub'''

Here the visualization examples:

1. Entity no selected, no highlighted
   [image: Entity no selected, no highlighted]
2. Entity "highlighted"
   [image: Entity highlighted]
3. Entity selected
   [image: Entity selected]

Answer (score 0):

You can select entities in VBA by select group.

```
 ThisDrawing.SendCommand ("_SELECT" + vbCr + "G" + vbCr + GroupName + vbCr + vbCr)
```

So first You need to create selectionset, then make a group from selectionset. Full sample would be:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim ssh As AcadSelectionSet
    Dim Ftyp(1) As Integer
    Dim Fdat(1) As Variant
    Dim BlockName As String
    BlockName = "A-1"
    Dim F1, F2 As Variant
    Ftyp(0) = 0: Fdat(0) = "Insert"
    Ftyp(1) = 2: Fdat(1) = BlockName
    Set sstest = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add("sstest")
    F1 = Ftyp
    F2 = Fdat
    sstest.Select acSelectionSetAll, , , Ftyp, Fdat
     
    Dim GroupName As String
    GroupName = "sstest"

    Dim group As AcadGroup
    Set group = ThisDrawing.Groups.Add(GroupName)
    For Each Item In sstest
        group.AppendItems (Item)
    Next
    sstest.Delete
    ThisDrawing.SendCommand ("_SELECT" + vbCr + "G" + vbCr + GroupName + vbCr + vbCr)
    group.Delete
End Sub
```

This sample code mark selected blocks (by name). Now You should change the way of selection. But it's not the question, so I hope You will handle it easy.